# Rails 5 How to validate encrypted field when using strongbox gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using [strongbox](https://github.com/spikex/strongbox) to encrypt some credit card numbers for a fun project (I know its not a good Idea to store this kind of sensitive data), however I'm unable to implement validations on it, I want to be able to validate my model's encrypted data using regex, for example I have a specific regex to validate visa & master card numbers, but when implementing this gem I'm unable to validate them.

this is how my model looks like:

```
class CreditCard < ApplicationRecord
  encrypt_with_public_key :card_number, :key_pair => Rails.root.join('config','keypair.pem')

  # ASSOCIATIONS
  # --------------------------------

  belongs_to :wallet
  delegate :user, to: :wallet, allow_nil: true

  # VALIDATIONS
  # --------------------------------
  validates :card_number, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :card_number
  validates_format_of :card_number, with: visa_regex, if: :visa?
end
```

I attempted to create an alternative method and validate that instead but to no avail:

```
class CreditCard < ApplicationRecord
  encrypt_with_public_key :card_number, :key_pair => Rails.root.join('config','keypair.pem')

  # ASSOCIATIONS
  # --------------------------------

  belongs_to :wallet
  delegate :user, to: :wallet, allow_nil: true

  # VALIDATIONS
  # --------------------------------
  BRANDS = %w(visa mastercard american_express)

  validates :card_number, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :card_number
  validates_format_of :card_number, with: visa_regex, if: :visa?

  def decrypted_card_number
    card_number.decrypt ENV['ENC_PASS']
  end

  def has_funds?(amount)
    true
  end  
end
```

Comment: So what is actually happening and what did you expect? Also: please remove all non essential code from your question, e.g. there are a lot irrelevant validations.

Comment: @mbuechmann I want to be able to validate my model's encrypted data using regex, for example I have a specific regex to validate visa & master card numbers, but when implementing this gem I'm unable to validate them

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you out that info into your question, it will be much easier to understand for other readers.